# Multiple IP camera setup

Tags: port-forwarding, webcam

Can anyone help me understand how to set up multiple IP cameras?

I have one working fine. Set up port forwarding and used No-ip to sort dynamic ip addresses.

So to add a second or third camera, what do I do? Each has it's own internal IP address, so that's fine, but all the cameras appear on the wifi network as the same device type. So I think this will be a problem with the port forwarding rules?

Answer (score 0):

Port forwarding rules are entirely based on IP address. Host names aren't important, and anything that deals with "device types" is only an invention of your router's fancy web UI and generally has nothing to do with how the packets are handled underneath.

Your configuration should work fine, as long as the cameras do not lose their IP addresses.